# Groupby select rows on Condition Taking two much time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that contains 1048576 rows.
The dataset has `order_id` and `status` columns.

I want to groupby order_id and select those order_id 's whose status is 5.

```
order = order.groupby(['order_id']).apply(lambda x: x.where(x.status == 5))
```

Example
order_id    status
id1          5
id1          3
id1          4
id1          6
id2          5
id2          3
id2          4
id2          6
It is taking too much time to execute, I want to optimize the following function. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to `groupby`?

Comment: Just use `order[order['status'].eq(5)]`

Comment: beacuse the One order_id have many status like                                                                   id1 5